# mysql query count by user and file name based on different columns value

Tags: mysql, count

I am trying to write a query where I count the number of times a file has been viewed and the number of times it has been downloaded on a per user basis.

```
Dataset
Userid | callaction | description
1      | Viewed     | abc.pdf
2      | Viewed     | abc.pdf
2      | Viewed     | xyz.pdf
1      | Viewed     | abc.pdf
1      | Downloaded | abc.pdf
1      | Downloaded | abc.pdf
1      | Downloaded | abc.pdf
2      | Downloaded | xyz.pdf
1      | Downloaded | xyz.pdf
```

My query is:

```
select userid, description, 
count(description) as 'Number of views',
count(description) as 'Number of Downloads'
from tablename
where callaction = 'VIEWFILE' OR callaction = 'DOWNLOAD'
group by userid, description;
```

But this is giving me a table where the Viewed and Downloaded are the same which is wrong

The result I am looking for is:

```
Userid | callaction | description | Number of views | Number of Downloads
1      | Viewed     | abc.pdf     | 2               |  3
1      | Viewed     | xyz.pdf     | 0               |  1
2      | Viewed     | abc.pdf     | 1               |  0
2      | Viewed     | xyz.pdf     | 1               |  1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select userid, description, 
       sum(callaction = 'VIEWFILE') as 'Number of views',
       sum(callaction = 'DOWNLOAD') as 'Number of Downloads'
from tablename
group by userid, description;
```